# Problem with PAM authorization in Dovecot

Tags: postfix, pam, dovecot, sasl

I've been using postfix with sasl and dovecot for many years.  Three days ago, authorization for dovecot via PAM stopped working which means no IMAP or POP3. SASL was working as I could tunnel in with `openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:993`

However this happens:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
a login validuser validpw
a NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
a logout
* BYE Logging out
a OK Logout completed.
```

I changed from `driver = pam` to `driver = shadow` in the file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext` and it works now.  This bothers me since it took 2 days to fix and I still don't know why PAM broke.

I'm using Wily Werewolf.

`uname -a`: `Ubuntu 15.10 Linux host.com 4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 22:15:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into what may be the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.4 after applying an update.  A working dovecot configuration started getting failures on all authentication requests.

The fix that worked for me was in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf.
Uncomment this line:

```
#default_vsz_limit = 256M
```

and raise the limit.  I set it to:

```
default_vsz_limit = 512M
```

The clue was these slightly mangled messages in syslog (after setting `auth_verbose=yes` in `10-logging.conf`).

```
Apr 21 20:48:19 mailserver t of memory [3273]
Apr 21 20:48:21 mailserver dovecot: auth-worker(3273): pam(xxxxx,xx.xx.xx.xx): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
```

The update (I think) installed a new version of PAM, and something must have gotten bigger.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work.  Maybe someone at debian or ubuntu should look at this?